# Adding a legend to a pie chart using highcharter, or Rcharts

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, rcharts

I need to add a legend to a piechart using any highcharts package for R on a shiny app(highcharter, rcharts, whatever).

Ex. Code

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

data(citytemp)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Highcharter Demo"),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4, class = "panel",
           selectInput("type", label = "Type", width = "100%",
                       choices = c("line", "column", "bar", "spline")), 
           selectInput("stacked", label = "Stacked",  width = "100%",
                       choices = c(FALSE, "normal", "percent")),
           selectInput("theme", label = "Theme",  width = "100%",
                       choices = c(FALSE, "fivethirtyeight", "economist",
                                   "darkunica", "gridlight", "sandsignika",
                                   "null", "handdrwran", "chalk")
           )
    ),
    column(width = 8,
           highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "500px")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {
  
  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({
    
    hc <- hc_demo() %>%
      hc_rm_series("Berlin") %>% 
      hc_chart(type = 'pie')
    
    if (input$stacked != FALSE) {
      hc <- hc %>%
        hc_plotOptions(showInLegend=TRUE,dataLabels=FALSE)
    }
    hc
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The code runs a crappy example of a pie chart, and no matter where I look I can't find an example of a highcharts pie chart with legends.

Attempts to fix it include:

> hc_legend(enabled=TRUE) <-- does not work, makes no change.
>
> hc_plotOptions(showInLegend=TRUE,dataLabels=FALSE) <-- Again, no change
>
> Using Rcharts with similar attempts, they both failed, I then became hopelessly lost looking through source code for highcharts

Using similar functionality I was able to create highchart pie charts with legends in a typical JS format by using either of the two solutions above, does anybody have a reasonable solution to this problem? Possibly a link to a decent resource for figuring it out?

actual JS example of highcharts with legend, shamelessly ripped from offical highcharts website.

```js
$(function () {

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Build the chart
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Brands',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                    y: 56.33
                }, {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 24.03,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                }, {
                    name: 'Firefox',
                    y: 10.38
                }, {
                    name: 'Safari',
                    y: 4.77
                }, {
                    name: 'Opera',
                    y: 0.91
                }, {
                    name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                    y: 0.2
                }]
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: You can try to prepare your own HTML legend, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/N3KAC/1/

Comment: @SebastianBochan I'll let you know how it goes. I might be able to incorporate that into R or shiny.

Comment: Sorry Im not familiar with the R gems etc ;)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, in your example the `hc_demo()` is a line chart example, so it will not work well just by changing the type of the chart due to the data is not coded as required for a pie chart (`y` and `name` values).

Here are is a raw example. As you showed in the javascript example you just need to force to show the legend because for pie charts the default value is `false`. This is achieved using plotOptions -> pie -> showInLegend = TRUE.

```
library(highcharter)
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "pie") %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(showInLegend = TRUE)
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = list(
    list(y = 3, name = "cat 1"),
    list(y = 4, name = "cat 2")
    )
  )
```

Finally I recommend you check [replicating highcharts demos in highcharter](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highcharter/vignettes/replicating-highcharts-demos.html).

Comment: Nice, concise example.